# want to create box view and list view products list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create box view and list view layout, so that user can view the product list with their own format. Please check http://www.pricealley.co.uk/Electronics , at body top right corner has two icons. I want these features.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the way they did this was by creating both views and toggling between views using jQuery.

In your HTML layout:

```
View 1:
<div id="grid"> ... </div>

View 2:
<div id="list"> ... </div>
```

In your jQuery you can say:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $(div#grid_icon).click( function() {
        $(div#grid).show();
        $(div#list).hide();
    }),

    $(div#list_icon).click( function() {
        $(div#grid).hide();
        $(div#list).show();
    })
};
```

Hope it helps.